# About signals in python with os module

Tags: python

I was studying the signals topic in python and came across this example

```
import signal
import os
import time

def receive_signal(signum, stack):
    print 'Received:', signum

signal.signal(signal.SIGUSR1, receive_signal)
signal.signal(signal.SIGUSR2, receive_signal)

print 'My PID is:', os.getpid()

while True:
    print 'Waiting...'
    time.sleep(3)
```

Now he is sending the signal using this

```
I ran signal_signal.py in one window, then kill -USR1 $pid, kill -USR2 $pid, and kill -INT $pid in another.
```

I have few problems

1. how can linux kill command is way of sending siganls . i dont get it
2. what is `kill -USR1` from where did `USR`  came from , what parameter is kill command expecting

i was thinking kill only kills the process id , why are we passing the parameter to kill command for

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `kill` command is a little bit misnamed. It sends signals to processes, and the *default signal* is `SIGTERM`, process termination. Using `kill` for sending `SIGUSR*` signals is perfectly correct.

When you have questions about a UNIX command, your best bet is to type in `man <commandname>` on the command line. `man kill` would have told you all this and more.

Try running `kill -l` for a list of supported signals. You can specify signals by number, by symbolic name and by symbolic name prepended by `SIG`. You can use `kill -10`, `kill -USR1` or `kill -SIGUSR1`, all would send the same signal. See the [`kill` manpage](http://linux.die.net/man/1/kill) for more details.

Comment: from where i can find what each signal does and what is it used for ,

Comment: @user192082107: Apart from `SIGKILL` and `SIGSTOP` (which cannot be caught, it's basically up to the receiving process how to handle incoming signals. `SIGTERM` does mean that the process should clean up and exit, but it could still ignore it (and then you'd have to use `SIGKILL` to terminate it). See the [UNIX signal Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_signal) for more details.